# Suppose f is a uniformly continuous real-valued function defned on a bounded set E in R: Prove that the range of f is a bounded set.

Tags: real-analysis

How would I go about this?

My intuition goes like this. If the range of f is not bounded, then there is not a real number such that the f(x) <= that number for all x in the set. Then it is impossible that the set is bounded, so it has the property that there does not exist a real number that is larger than |x - y| for all x in the set. Meaning the set is unbounded, which is a contradiction. It seems kind of obvious but how do I make it more rigorous.

Comment: Where did you use the assumption that $f$ is uniformly continuous?

Comment: Your argument doesn't really make sense to me. You don't need proof-by-contradiction for this

Comment: Uniform continuity implies that $f$ extends continuously to $\overline{E}$. The image of a compact set by a continuous function is compact.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would really go about this to be honest

Comment: Bounded subsets of reals are totally bounded. Use the $\delta$ from uniform continuity to obtain $N$ balls which cover the set of radius $\delta$, so the function is uniformly continuous on each ball. See if you can finish from here